# JS : Call print function from other file

Tags: javascript

i have a.html which is

**a.html**

```
    <script>
    function printContent(el){
        var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
        var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
    }
    </script>
<div id="div1">DIV 1 content...</div>
<button onclick="printContent('div1')">Print Content</button>
```

i want to print contain in a.html which the button is in b.html

**b.html**

```
<a href="#" onclick="printContent("printJS")">Print</a>
```

How to pass the func to other file?

thanks

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818854/javascript-import-html-is-it-possible. What you are doing doesn't make much sense. You can have your functions in separate files and import those js scripts.

Comment: Are you trying to print the contents of the other window?

Comment: yes, of course @JaredFarrish how to do it?

Comment: This question gives you the general idea, you can also print up with things like `top.print()` or `window.parent`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852190/js-window-open-then-print

Comment: Plus, if you're trying to push contents from your current window into another, skip that and use stylesheets or a "print div". It's easy enough to google for that.

Answer (score 2):

Extract your function to separate *.js file and include this file in both html files.

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```