# Inserting HTML text in js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I import a html file in to javascript code?

Currently I have to do something like:

```
document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML = '<li class="topline"><a href="#">some text</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">some text </a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#"some text</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>';
```

How do I separate the js code and html code in to separate files. Later load the html code into javascript easily?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Comment: You mean that you want to have that particular `<li>...</li>` code in a separate html file so you can get it to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript import html is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818854/javascript-import-html-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this! taken from the below reference link!

You need to put the ul and li tags inside a file called `import.htm`, also its needs to be in the same place as the current file.

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "import.htm", false);
ajax.send();
document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML += ajax.responseText;
```

**Reference:**

1. [javascript import HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818854/javascript-import-html-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 0):

Just like this

```
$("#menu").load('menu.html #menulist');
```

then in HTML file do this

```
<ul id ="menulist">
<li class="topline"><a href="#">some text</a></li>  
<li><a href="#">some text </a></li>  
<li><a href="#">some text</a></li>  
<li><a href="#">some text</a></li>  
<li><a href="#"some text</a></li>  
<li><a href="#">some text</a></li>  
<li><a href="#">some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

For better reference

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818854/javascript-import-html-is-it-possible)